# Why is my specialized template function invoked only in debug builds?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have templated functions in my C++11 Xcode project and some of them have specializations. However, I have discovered that the specializations only get called in debug builds; if I build in release, they are ignored.

I have successfully created a very simple example:

**special.h**

```
#include <cstdio>

struct special
{
    template<typename T>
    void call(const T&) { puts("not so special"); }
};
```

**special.cpp**

```
#include "special.h"
#include <string>

template<>
void special::call(const std::string&) { puts("very special"); }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "special.h"
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello world";
    special s;
    s.call(123);
    s.call(str);
}
```

[You can download the project](http://wikisend.com/download/566650/special.zip) (until somewhere this summer of 2013 at least) to reproduce the issue if you don't want to create it yourself. First run the project with the debug configuration, then run it again in release. The output that I expect is:

> not so special
>   very special

And this is indeed what I get with the Debug build configuration. However, with Release, I get this:

> not so special
>   not so special

Which means the specialized implementation of `special::call` in special.cpp was ignored.

Why is the result inconsistent? What should I do to ensure that the specialized function is called in release builds?

Comment: Put it in the .h instead of the .cpp?

Comment: special.cpp is linked in both cases?

Comment: Yes, special.cpp is compiled and linked in both cases. If I put the specialization in the header file, it works if the file is included in just one .cpp file, but otherwise I get a duplicate symbol error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your program has UB. An explicit specialisation or at least its declaration must be visible before being used. [temp.expl.spec]§6:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Add this declaration to `special.h`:

```
template<>
void special::call(const std::string&);
```

Alternatively, you can put the specialistation itself into the header. However, as a specialisation is no longer a template, it follows normal function rules and must be marked `inline` if placed in a header.

Also, be careful that function template specialisations have rather specific behaviour, and it's generally better to use overloads than specialisations. See [Herb Sutter's article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) for details.

Answer (score 8):

You violated the one definition rule (ODR). So what happens exactly? In `main.cpp` there is no specialization known for `special::call<string>`. Therefore the compiler generates an instantiation of the template into that translation unit (TU) that outputs "not so special". In `special.cpp` there is a full specialization declared and defined, so the compiler puts that definition into the other translation unit. So you have two different definitions of the very same function in two different translation units, which is a violation of the ODR which means it is undefined behavior.

In theory, the outcome can be anything. A compiler error, a crash, a silent online order for a pizza, *anything*. Even different behavior in debug and release compiles.

In practice, I *guess* the following happens: When linking the debug build, the Linker sees the same symbol defined twice in the two TUs, which is allowed only for templates and inline functions. Because of the ODR it may assume that both definitions are equivalent and picks the one from `special.cpp`, so you get by coincidence the behavior you expect.
During release build, the compiler inlines the call to `special::call<string>` during the compilation of `main.cpp`, so you get the only behavior seen in that TU: "not so special".

So how can you fix this?
In order to have only one definition for that specialization, you have to *define* it in one TU as you did, but you have to *declare* that there is a full specialization in any other TU, meaning declare that the specialization exists in the header `special.h`:

```
// in special.h
template<>
void special::call(const std::string&);
```

Or, which is seen more often, *define* it in the header, so it's seen in every TU. Since fully specialized function templates are normal functions, you will have to define it inline:

```
// in special.h
template<>
inline void special::call(const std::string&)
{ 
  puts("very special"); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for a full explanation of what is going on, and not just the correction required. As to the selection of the function from `specials.cpp` I would surmise that it is due to the order in which the `.o` files are passed to the linker; specifically I suspect that `specials.o` is passed prior to `main.o`.

Comment: I guess that's the *very* implementation specific part. It will depend on the order in which the linker *processes* the object files, what in turn depends on the order in which the object files are passed to it via the command line. And it might depend on how the linker stores and looks up the symbols it finds in the two TUs. That may be anything, but I guess too that the most obvious would be first object files passed is the first processed, and first time the symbol is found is the only one that gets stored and called.

Comment: Oh you are right it seems very implementation specific, but since apparently the behavior is *stable*, there is probably an explanation.